# Akka Remote - Messages are not delivering (Java)

Tags: java, akka

Trying to use Akka for parallel computing but facing a problem while communicating actors. I have two different actors (whose names are sender and receiver) which works on two different systems working on different ports on same ip address (whose names are SenderSystem and Receiver System). What I want to do is send message from sender actor to receiver actor. But on console I see a message like this

```
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:36:51.645] [SenderSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://SenderSystem/sender] Message [com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.Messages$1] from Actor[akka://SenderSystem/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SenderSystem/sender] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Here is *application.conf*

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
  untrusted-mode = off
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    } 

 }
}
```

sender.conf

```
include "application"
akka { 
    actor {
        deployment {
          /receiver {
            remote = "akka://ReceiverSystem@127.0.0.1:8091"
          }
        }
      }
    remote.netty.tcp.port = 8090
}
```

receiver.conf

```
include "application"
akka {
    remote.netty.tcp.port = 8091
}
```

Receiver.java

```
package com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.receiver;

import com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.Messages;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class Receiver extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg.equals(Messages.RECEIVE)) {
            System.out.println("receiver receives");
        }
    }

}
```

ReceiverApplication.java

```
package com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.receiver;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class ReceiverApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startRecieverSystem();
    }

    private static void startRecieverSystem() {
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ReceiverSystem",
                ConfigFactory.load("receiver"));
        ActorRef actorOf = system.actorOf(Props.create(Receiver.class),
                "receiverActor");
        System.out.println("created receiver actor: " + actorOf.toString());
    }
}
```

Sender.java

```
package com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.sender;

import akka.actor.ActorSelection;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

import com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.Messages;

public class Sender extends UntypedActor {

    public Sender() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg.equals(Messages.SEND)) {
            System.out.println(getSender() + " sends");
            ActorSelection receiverActor = getContext().actorSelection(
                    "akka.tcp://ReceiverSystem@127.0.0.1:8091/user/receiver"); // I am not sure about this one
            receiverActor.tell(Messages.RECEIVE, getSelf());
        }
    }

}
```

SenderApplication.java

```
package com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.sender;

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;

public class SenderApplication {
    private static ActorSystem system;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startSenderApp();
    }

    private static void startSenderApp() {
        setSystem(ActorSystem.create("SenderSystem",
                ConfigFactory.load("sender")));
        ActorRef actorOf = getSystem().actorOf(Props.create(Sender.class),
                "senderActor");
        System.out.println("created sender actor: " + actorOf.toString());
    }

    public static ActorSystem getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    public static void setSystem(ActorSystem system) {
        SenderApplication.system = system;
    }
}
```

And lastly, main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReceiverApplication.main(null);
    SenderApplication.main(null);
    ActorSystem system = SenderApplication.getSystem();
    ActorSelection ref = system.actorSelection("sender");
    ref.tell(Messages.SEND, ActorRef.noSender());
}
```

entire console output

```
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.220] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.451] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ReceiverSystem@127.0.0.1:8091]
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.451] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://ReceiverSystem@127.0.0.1:8091]
created receiver actor: Actor[akka://ReceiverSystem/user/receiverActor#2084584126]
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.481] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.491] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://SenderSystem@127.0.0.1:8090]
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.491] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://SenderSystem@127.0.0.1:8090]
created sender actor: Actor[akka://SenderSystem/user/senderActor#-2012370784]
[INFO] [08/15/2015 12:48:12.491] [SenderSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://SenderSystem/sender] Message [com.aliyesilkanat.akkadeneme.Messages$1] from Actor[akka://SenderSystem/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SenderSystem/sender] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `ActorSystem` is local(same JVM) then call is `akka://ActorSystem/user/ActorName`. In your main method are:

```
ActorSelection ref = system.actorSelection("sender");
```

try replace the `sender` for `akka://SenderSystem/user/senderActor`

Comment: Thx I lot! But I have mistaken receiver actor's address too. It should be like this. 
    akka.tcp://ReceiverSystem@127.0.0.1:8091/user/receiverActor

Comment: `receiverActor` is remote.

Answer (score 1):

You have in sender conf , remote deployment, so you can create Receiver actor remotly from Sender actor

```
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(Receiver.class), "receiver");
actor.tell(Messages.SEND, ActorRef.noSender());
```